# Linear algebra, Linear Transformations

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and let $W$
be a 
subspace of $V$. If $f$ is a linear functional on $W$, prove that there is a
linear functional $g$ on V such that $g\left( v\right) =f\left( v\right) $
for each $v$ in the subspace $W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_p)$ a basis for $W$ and we complete it on a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$. Now define $g$ by

$$g(e_i)=f(e_i),\; i=1,\ldots,p$$
and for example

$$g(e_i)=0,\; i=p+1,\ldots,n$$
then $f$ and $g$ are equal on $W$ since they are equal on a basis of $W$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Take any basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_k\}\;$ of $\;W\;$ and expand it to a basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_k,u_{k+1},...,u_n\}\;$ of V.

Use that any *linear* transformation is uniquely and completely determined by its values on any basis of the space.

Define now

$$g(u_i)=\begin{cases}f(u_i)&,\;\;1\le i\le k\\{}\\0&,\;\;k+1\le i\le n\end{cases}$$